# Finding determinant of matrix using Lower triangular matrix

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, determinants

I have algorithms for finding determinant of matrix and pre-transforming it to upper triangular matrix form:

```
clear all;
A = rand([3 3])*100;
B = A;
N = size(A);
for K = 1 : N-1
    for I = K+1 : N
        for J = K:N
            if J == K
                aik = A(I,K);
            end
            A(I,J) = (A(I,J) - aik/A(K,K)*A(K,J));
        end
    end
end
det = 1;
for I = 1:N
    det = det*A(I,I);
end
```

This code works very well. Now I would like to develop a similar algorithm, but for the case of a lower triangular matrix. How I can do that? Importantly, I need to use MATLAB without calling any external functions.

Comment: Be more specific. What did you actually try? In what way did it "not work out"?

Comment: I don't understand. If you *know* the starting matrix is lower triangular, then there is no work to do really. The resulting upper triangular matrix will simply be the diagonal of your original matrix, and the determinant is simply the product of the diagonal of your original matrix. Your code seems to handle this just fine. What is not working out for you?

Comment: No, starting matrix can be different. I should transform it into lower triangular. I try to change index I,J,K in my algorithm, but matrix is not stay lower triangular.

Comment: Ah, got it. But in that case it would have been best for you to post the code that isn't working so we can comment on that and suggest corrections.

Comment: Ok, it's little bit more interesting then i think. My error consist in syntaxis of MATLAB language. Because when i use increment like `K = 1 : N-1` i can not write value of increment(1), BUT if i use decrement in other direction, like `K = N-1:1`, i should strong definite it like -1, i mean `K = N-1:-1:1`. I think it's anser for question.

Comment: do you think it's ok that your resulting upper matrix does not match the resulting upper matrix of [L,U]=lu(A)  ?

Comment: Also realize that N = size(A) creates a two-element vector, not a single value. So your subsequent use of N in for-loops probably isn't what you intended. You should probably use N = size(A,1) instead.

Comment: @JohnBG, of course yes. It's not cutting by diagonal, it's more complicated algorithm for finding determinant. You can compare results using internal function det

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct solution:

```
clear all;
A = rand([5 5])*100;
det(A);
B = A;
N = size(A);
for K = N:-1: 1
    for I = K-1:-1: 1
        for J = N:-1:1
            if J == K
                aik = A(I,K);
            end
            A(I,J) = (A(I,J) - aik/A(K,K)*A(K,J));
        end
    end
end
det = 1;
for I = N:-1:1
    det = det*A(I,I);
end
```

Comment: please add explanation also.. how your code solves the problem.